# Installing MPLAB IDE 8.x

Tags: ide, mplab

I am trying to download and install MPLAB IDE from Microchip downloads archive.

https://www.microchip.com/development-tools/pic-and-dspic-downloads-archive

But the download links for 8.x serial do not work. I left click on them and nothing happens. I try to open link by right clicking and selecting open but a pop-up says right click is disabled.

Left clicking on MPLAB X IDE links on the same page works fine. So does all the other links except for the ones for MPLAB IDE.

What is the problem? And how can I download MPLAB IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link
http://www.digitale-elektronik.de/shopsystem/product_info.php?products_id=631

But you should think about MPLABX. MPLAB 8.x is pretty old and don't have any support for the newer Controller.